# Angular get typed character from ngModel and replace it inside the input

Tags: javascript, angular, input

How is it possible to get the new typed character (not the whole new value of the ngModel) then apply logic on it, then returning a new value for the ngModel ?

**Example:** let's say when a user types inside an input we want to take the **new character** he types then change it to something and append it to the previous value of the ngModel. Tried `keypress` and `onModelChange` but didn't seem to work

```
<ion-textarea #chat_input
     (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)"
     placeholder="Text Input"
     [ngModel]="editorMsg"
     (keyup.enter)="sendMsg()"
     (ionFocus)="onFocus()">
</ion-textarea>
```

And My method is like:

```
modelChanged(e){
        // e is the new value of editorMsg and not the new typed character, if I get the new character I can do
this.editorMsg+=e;
}
```

But I get only the new typed value from `modelChange` how can I get only the new typed character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
modelChanged(e){
  let lastChar;
  if (e.length) {
      lastChar = e[e.length -1]; // this gets the last character of the srting..
     // do you logic with lastChar..
   }
}
```

Comment: But this won't necessarily give you the last typed character, correct? If the user types a backspace for example, this will give you the current last character in the string, not the last *typed* character.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you’re looking for is the `keyup` event.

You could have something like

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

And then in your component

```
onKey(event: any) { 
    console.log(event.key)
}
```

The important bit here is to use the `event.key` and not `event.target.value`. If you used the latter one it would always give you the input value instead of the input key

You can get more information for what you need [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input), where I got the relevant bit from

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but for keyup, if I press backspace or enter or space, I will get a string saying `Space` or `Enter`...etc which doesn't work for me

Comment: Well the goal was to be able to capture single keys on each press in an input. You could then have a regular expression to filter out the ones you don’t want. With a simple regular expression you could immediately return from your method in case the character was not one of the expected ones.

Answer (score 0):

It works using `(ngModelChange)`. See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrizck?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

#### component.html

```
<input [ngModel]="name" (keypress)="onKeypress($event)">
```

#### component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'try me';

  onKeypress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
     console.log(event);
     // Do what you want...
     this.name = event.key;
     event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: the replace is just an example, the desired behavior is when something is typed we perform whatever logic we want and the value is displayed to the input, with `ngModelChange` we get only the new `name` and not the new character

Comment: Can you be more specific plz? I don't see why it won't work in your case.

Comment: Okay to be clear, I want to be able to get the new character if a user presses `a` then I want to get `a` and then after applying my logic send the result inside `name`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, check the edited question for more clarification

Comment: Edited to perfom logic based on the key pressed